# Split a String in Java with with "|f|n|0:" separator?

Tags: java, regex, split, line

I know how to split a String with split() method but unfortunately my separator seems to be interpreted as regex (splitting the string in single characters) and I don't know how to force otherwise.
I could also use something similar to getLine (it would be better for memory consumption, too) but I don't know how to use arbitrary separator in Java.
I can't change separator, it's from hardware.

Comment: `\\|` Or `Pattern.quote("|")`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried some similar escapes and also that but with only one backslash. Now I understand the regex wants one \ to escape | as character and not altarnation and I have to escape \ with another backslash, is it correct? [|] works, too. What about getline?

Answer (score 0):

what you want  get in result ?  is the result  have to be  f  n   0     or  f n 0: ?

---

its have 2 different way  one is seperate  1 letter after |  the result is  f n 0

and the next one is seperate  just one  |  the result is   f n 0:
if you want any thing more  ask

Comment: answer so i can help you